# Codeigniter not finding the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my basic file structure

```
/system
- /application
- /config
- - -routes.php
- /controllers
- - -about.php
- - -home.php
- - /admin
- - - -dashboard.php
- - - -login.php
- - - -news.php
```

And in routes:

```
$route['admin']        = 'admin/dashboard'; //This should be the default.
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';
```

Browsing to http://mywebsite.com/admin results in this error;

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: dashboard.php
```

I've read the documentation on controllers and sub-folders are supported. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The file dashboard.php was a view, not a controller.

I had a line `$this->view->load('no/folder/here/dashboard.php');` which was throwing the error.

It's probably a good idea to name all the view files view_dashboard.php to help identify which file does what.

Answer (score 1):

Only because the someone has fubar'd the proper folder structure, there should be a 'views' folder which would avoid any confusion :/

Comment: It is in the views folder. It just isn't too helpful when the error doesn't tell me which folder or which line the error has occurred on.

Maybe I should have a debug log running :)

Comment: Ahh sorry matey, I thought the basic structure you posted was complete ;)